# Where can I ask questions about the setup of self-made applications?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have made a C# application and I am wondering where I should ask about the installation / setup etc. I don't think it's a question for Stack Overflow. Maybe for the Programmers SE website? Could anyone tell me where I could ask such a question? The question I am wanting to ask is:

> When I publish my windows form application(via build -> publish application), where can I find the app config of this application since it's already installed? and how to configure etc.

Of course with more details. I don't think this will be a success on Stack Overflow since a question there without code will get a heap of downvotes.

Comment: Why the 2 downvotes?

Comment: If you have a question in mind, could you perhaps include it here? Then we have a better idea where we could tell you to go.

Comment: @Bart See editted question :) and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems very much a technical question about a tool used in software development. The last part, "how to configure etc", is too open-ended and may get your question closed as "too broad". You may want to make the scope of that a bit narrower.

It's been a while since I last used Visual Studio (which I assume you're using), so I don't know if the answer is easy to find. It may be that the answer is looking you straight in the face, and you've just overlooked it. (Doesn't that happen to all of us at one time or another?) In that case, you could get downvoted. So be sure to add what you have done to find the answer yourself, show that you have done research. Also check if the answer isn't already on Stack Overflow, or your question might be closed as a duplicate.

So, if you can't find the answer yourself, and can show that you have looked and tried to solve your own problem first, by all means post this one on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am also saying behind that:"Of course more detailed" but anyway thanks for the answer